# jQuery — how to animate a div using height:auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div that expands downward when a user presses "more." The div's height is always auto, and expands to fit the content accordingly.

I need to keep "height:auto" so that the CSS remains responsive when the screen is resized, but I want the changing height to be animated...how should I do that?

In other words, when the user presses more and additional content is added to this div, I want the div's expansion to be animated, without specifying a certain height like 5em or anything.

```
<div id="expand">
    <p>This is the div I want to expand</p>
    <div id="hidden" style="display:none">
       <img />
       <img />
    </div>
</div>
```

Got it! I need to use the slideToggle method on the  instead of the  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly how you set up your code, but jQuery

```
$(link).on("click", function() {
   $(element).slideToggle();
});
```

might work for you.

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: slideToggle looks like something that might work. I just put some sample code in my question. When the user presses "more", it changes the display of the inner div to block. How do I format the jQuery now?

Comment: What exactly is your question? If you can be more specific I can set up a fiddle for you.

Comment: Oh that would be awesome. I want the inner div to expand when the user presses "more", and the div to collapse when the user presses "less".

Comment: sorry for my late comment back.. i had a phone call. here is the fiddle. let me know if you need any more help with it, or is that basic example enough for you?

http://jsfiddle.net/WB64k/

Answer (score 2):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/botuy/1/edit)** <-- Resize the window. Works great.

You can do it simply like:

```
$('.more').click(function(){
  $("+ div", this).slideToggle();
});
```

having:

```
<button class="more">MORE</button>
<div>Lorem Ipsum...</div>
```

<sub>I would use the HTML you have, but that's the price when you did not showed some code in your Question ;)</sub>

Comment: slideToggle looks like something that might work. I just put some sample code in my question. When the user presses "more", it changes the display of the inner div to block. How do I format the jQuery now?

Comment: @user3661646 the issue in your HTML code and your desire is that once you open the `hidden` DIV, you'll not be able to interact (further clicks) with your content -> cause the parent will close.

Comment: @user3661646 so? What is the element that should trigger? the first `<p>` one?

Answer (score 0):

You can always:

```
var targetDiv = $('.targetDiv');
// get original Height
var originalHeight = targetDiv.height();
// get natural height
targetDiv.css({ height: 'auto'});
var naturalHeight = targetDiv.height();
// reset div to original height
targetDiv.css({height: originalHeight});
// animate to target height
targetDiv.animate({
   height: naturalHeight}, {
   duration: 1000,
   completion: function() {
      // set height to auto
      targetDiv.css({height: 'auto'});
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jQuery.  You just need to caluclate the `height: auto` absolute height.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CS2h9/